# How to choose my primary key?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, primary-key

I found this reading material on [choosing a primary key](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/primarykey.htm).

- Is there a guide / blog post on how to choose the primary key for a given table?
- Should I use a auto-incremented/generated key, or should I base the primary key on the data being modeled (assuming it has a truly unique field)?
- Should the primary key always be long for performance's sake, or can I take an external unique id as primary key, even if it's a string?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe that in practice using a [natural key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) is rarely better than a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key).

The following are the main disadvantages of using a natural key as the primary key:

- You might have an incorrect key value, or you may simply want to rename a key value. To edit it, you would have to update all the tables that would be using it as a foreign key.
- It is often difficult to have a truly [unique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) natural key.
- Natural keys are often strings. An index on an numeric field will be much more compact than one on a string field.

There is no hard rule on what the data type of the primary key should be. A numeric key normally performs better, but you could use a string, especially if the table is not big, and the tables that reference it are not big either.

Comment: +1 - I've had no end of hell from the combination of using natural keys in DB and admin personel insisting on reusing customer IDs because they don't want joeblogs13 if there are only 12 active Joe Blogs... in spite of it making every possible report wrong and leaving us with race conditions on every page of our website...

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo : So you would rather use a surrogate key than a VIN code for vehicles or ISBN codes for books as a primary key? Those code are ISO compliants, don't you think that if one is dealing with industry issue those will have a better effect than surrogate key ?

Comment: @Spredzy: In most cases yes. The first point that I mentioned could  still be very problematic. Primary Keys are not meant to be changed, and you could easily have a typo in an ISBN that you'd want to modify... There are often other complications with natural keys, such as (quoting [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number)): "Occasionally, a book may appear without a printed ISBN if it is printed privately or the author does not follow the usual ISBN procedure; however, this is usually later rectified"... These exceptions are difficult to deal with...

Comment: ... I sometimes use a natural key for a "countries" table using the "ISO 3166-1" two-letter code as the primary key, but with hindsight, even these change occasionally... A surrogate key usually makes everything much simpler.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for those answers. Very useful answers.

Comment: A surrogate key won't stop a ISBN or country code from being duplicated. It also won't allow database users to identify books and countries correctly. From a data integrity and usability perspective, choose keys that are familiar, simple and stable. Whether or not a table also has a surrogate key is very much a secondary consideration and should not be the decisive factor in identifying and implementing keys.

Comment: It would be fair if you listed also the disadvantages from wiki: disassociation, query optimization, normalization, business process modeling, inadvertent disclosure and inadvertent assumptions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key#Disadvantages_of_Surrogate_Keys). Unless you keep these things in check using surrogate keys can destroy the value of large portions of data, where natural keys typically exhibit problems only in borderline cases (and actually signal that you need to change the system; which is work that you *can* skip with surrogates at the risk of ruining your data)

Answer (score 2):

I use **surrogate** keys, often referred to as **non-sensical** keys, made up of an autogenerated int/bigint datatype.

Here are some of the reasons I like using these keys.

- When deleting several items from a list (such as old email) you can supply a comma separated list of integers instead of guids or natural keys
- I find it makes writing your own cascade deletes easier
- I think inner-joins are faster on integer fields
- It can make learning a new system without documentation easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

A key is a set of attributes with two fundamental features: uniqueness and minimality. Minimality means the key has only the minimum number of attributes required to ensure uniqueness.

There are three criteria commonly applied as a guide to choosing a good key:

- Familiarity - keys should be meaningful and familiar to the people who use them
- Simplicity - keys should be as simple and concise as possible
- Stability - key values should change infrequently

These are good guidelines but are not absolute requirements. In all cases functional requirements and the needs of data integrity should determine what keys to use.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of blog posts about primary keys:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/10/03/long-primary-key-for-innodb-tables/

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/03/13/to-uuid-or-not-to-uuid/

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with a lot of different data models in professional systems (mostly bank software) and there were different solutions. There was the GUID solution I have seen and it seemed not to have impacted the performances too much. I have seen the "number provided by a service as a system wide unique number". I have seen algorithms of providing something like a GUID "but shorter". I have seen also that the business key was used (like the account number) which is poor design and caused problems and I would not recommend it. I have seen the auto-incremented key for each table.

What did I like the most? The number provided by a service as a system wide number. It works well. And with a simple key translation table one can use a user key (like an account number) to find out what unique number and what sort of data object (not necessarily the table because the same unique key may apply to several tables if a data object is split up on different tables depending on its type).

So is there a blog or something? Well I have a book to recommend called "Data Modeling Essentials" by Graeme Simsion and Graham Witt. They might not suggest my preferred solution but they give many real live examples and show the different kind of solutions that are possible.

Answer (score -4):

I always choose uuid as a primary key. In comparison to int/long key, there is a slight overhead, but there are a lot of benefits: you cannot run into type overflow, you can shard database later on without changing primary keys, you can integrate with other systems and be sure that your primary keys are always unique, uuid cannot be guessed etc.

Comment: -1 sorry for the downvote but "always choose a uuid" vs. "use a uuid when appropriate" 4 bytes vs 36 - hmmm, fill those buffers !!