# Are the FK always related to the field "id" of the parent table? Is a bad practice point to another field?

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys

imagine i have a table Nation (name, iso_code_3, language, ..) and a table Culture (languages) with fields (name, ...). Now i have to create a foreing key (field language) in the table Nations that point to the table Culture (you know, a language is spoken in each nation).

So now I'm wondering about the foreign key in the table Nations, should be referenced to the field "id" or could i reference it directly to the field "name" (in both cases, of the table Culture) ??

My opinion: if for example I want to retrieve a row of Nation containing the language that is spoken, would be better to reference to the field "name". In that way I would avoid an INNER JOIN clause.

Regards

Javi

Comment: BTW, naming fields ID is a poor practice. It can cause query errors and is a pain for reporting. Use tableNameID instead.

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key should typically reference the primary key of the other table. Yes - it might look tempting to bind to the actual data field directly - but what if that is not unique, not clear which row you refer to??

A foreign key must always refer to a column in the referenced table that is at least UNIQUE - the primary key always is UNIQUE, so that' the prime candidate, of course.

Don't try to take shortcuts - SQL databases are pretty good at resolving JOINs - don't sacrifice data integrity for the sake of a "quickie" win.....

Answer (score 1):

You can point it to any field which is unique. If you point it to a field with string type data, the join will be slower than if you point it to an integer surrogate key particulalry if the string data is long.

Comment: It depends. A join on a string isn't necessarily slower than a join on an integer. In any case, the OP has said that by referencing the name he expects to *avoid* doing the join at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your description whether "culture" and "language" identify the same concept.  For example, Spain and Peru might be said to have different cultures, but both have the Spanish language.  Spain also has Catalan and Basque.  Peru also has Quechua.

Once you clear this up,  you might discover that you are doing a many-to-many join,  not using the PK in either table.  If this is correct, it has to do with a lot more than name versus identifying number.

As an example from another field,  mailing systems often do joins on zip-code, even though there is no master table of zip-codes in the database.  That's really a many-to-many join.  It's sometimes the right thing to do, but rarely.  Most commonly, the right thing is to establish a master table for the entity identified  (in your case "Language") and then do two plain old FK-PK joins.  Don't worry about a three way join.  With only a few hundred rows, the delay is not worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key can reference any candidate key in the table it references. For simplicity's sake it usually makes sense to pick one key per table (usually designated the "primary" key) to be used consistently for all foreign key references to that table - but there is no absolute reason why you must do that if you have a sound reason to do otherwise. Good criteria for choosing what keys to use are: [Familiarity, Simplicity and Stability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291990/how-to-choose-my-primary-key/4299907#4299907).

"Id" is a poor name for any column - key or not.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign Key can be created on any column of other table that has a Uniqueness enforced. Either a Primary Key or a Unique Index.
In your case it would be a good idea to point it to Language, if you make the Language unique.

Answer (score 0):

IN your exemple, you have a *many-to-many relationship*, since 1 country may speak several languages, an 1 language may be spoken in several countries.
So you should in fact be represented by a *relationship table*, that represents your m-to-m relation.
That table must contain the PK of both other tables.
The combination of those 2 FK is by definition the PK of your CountryLanguage table.