# Rails belongs_to returns nil class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to link two tables to each other

```
class Musers < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Email 
    # sid (student_id:integer)
    # isyk: boolean

    belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "smail"
end

class Users < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :muser, :foreign_key => "email"

end
```

But,

```
@user = Users.first
@user.muser returns nil
```

Comment: The answers provided explain the core issue, however there is also a problem with the way that you're generating `@user`. You shouldn't be pluralizing the model name. Instead, use `@user = User.first`.

Comment: @JamesChevalier user = Users.first creates the user not User.first, it says uninitialized constant

Comment: @Yagiz You should rename `Users` to `User` and `Musers` to `Muser`. Rails models should be named in their singular form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By saying `:foreign_key => "smail"` you are telling rails that the `Muser` column `smail` points to the `User` model's foreign key. This is most likely not the case.

Assuming that the primary key of the `User` models is called `id`, you should a user_id field to `Muser`, and change `belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "smail"` into:

```
belongs_to :user
```

On the `User` model you can define the reverse relation using:

```
has_one :muser
```

Also, to follow rails model naming conventions, you should rename `Users` to `User` and `Musers` to `Muser`.

You should read more about [belongs_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) and [has_one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association).

If, on the other hand, the `User` model in fact uses email for it's primary key, I would strongly advise you to change that and add an auto-incrementing primary key instead. As a rule of thumb, the primary key should be chosen such that it never changes. If it does change, all foreign keys pointing to that primary key will have to change as well.
You should only use a non auto-incrementing primary key if you have a specific reason for doing so.

More information on choosing a primary key: [How to choose my primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291990/how-to-choose-my-primary-key)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't just tell rails the type of association, you actually have to **set the association to an instance of that class**. For example, making a new muser will not automatically assign a user as the `belongs_to`. You could do something like

```
u = User.new
u.muser = Muser.first
u.save
```

However, I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with a belongs_to - belongs_to relationship, but you should know that you have to do more than just tell rails it exists.